# server gets disconnected suddenly within 2 or 3 seconds after connecting

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, application

Not sure Is this an issue with OS configuration or with my VRD (VisionApp Remote Desktop) application.

I have some servers in an environment, all with win 2008R2 OS. And I take RDP to these machines using VRD application. When I try to login to some servers, if terminal services exceeds connection, it would prompt me to disconnect a user before login, which is expected. But for some servers it just gets disconnected automatically, without displaying anything on the screen. That is, once I click connect in my VRD, after 2 or 3 seconds it gets disconnected automatically.

Not sure what the root cause is.Can someone please help me if ever you've experienced like this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the event logs?

Comment: @arcesso: No event logs.. no idea what is the real issue.. :(

Comment: That is a tough one.  You could try to sniff the traffic to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Check VisionApp forums for any bugs related to your software version and verify there isn't an update/patch available for the software.

Comment: Sounds dumb, but could someone else be taking over your session?

Comment: @serverstackqns did you got it solved, and if yes how? please add an answer or accept one please ;) - sounds like someone take the session - tried with an other user? yeh I know that I graveyard now a question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues with RDP connection. I can usually resolve them by resetting the RDP listener.

From a console, Start > Administrative Tools > Remote Desktop Services > RDS Manager

Go to the Session tab and look for a session called RDP-Tcp with a user called listener. Right click and reset. Should take less than a second to come back up.. Then attempt to RDP in.

Comment: Thanks.. But I didnt get any difference after doing this.. the issue still exists :(

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling sharing of any local resources to the remote session and see if the session continues to crash.

[image: Settings]